# Can I create a Unix Time type which automatically converts to datetime in Pydantic?

Tags: python, pydantic

I receive a JSON response like with a unix timestamp, e.g.:

```
{"protocol": "http", "isPublic": false, "startTime": 1607586354631}
```

The simplest way to read this data with Pydantic is to annotate `startTime` as `int`. I would like to annotate it as `UnixMicrotime` or similar, so that Pydantic also parses it to datetime (and converts a datetime back to UnixMicrotime when serializing). Is that possible?

### Minimal Example

```py
import json
from pydantic import BaseModel


class Data(BaseModel):
    protocol: str
    isPublic: bool
    startTime: int


json_str = """{"protocol": "http", "isPublic": false, "startTime": 1607586354631}"""
data_dict = json.loads(json_str)
data = Data.parse_obj(data_dict)
print(data)
```

gives

```
protocol='http' isPublic=False startTime=1607586354631
```

but I would like it to be:

```
protocol='http' isPublic=False startTime=2020-12-10T08:45:54
```

Answer (score 6):

You could annotate it as `datetime` to parse it, and add [custom `json_encoder`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/exporting_models/#json_encoders) for serializing `datetime` as unix time. Sample:

```py
import json
from datetime import datetime

from pydantic import BaseModel

json_str = """{"protocol": "http", "isPublic": false, "startTime": 1607586354631}"""
data_dict = json.loads(json_str)


class Data(BaseModel):
    protocol: str
    isPublic: bool
    startTime: datetime


data = Data.parse_obj(data_dict)
print(data.json())


class DataWithUnixTime(BaseModel):
    protocol: str
    isPublic: bool
    startTime: datetime

    class Config:
        json_encoders = {
            datetime: lambda v: v.timestamp(),
        }


data = DataWithUnixTime.parse_obj(data_dict)
print(data.json())
```

```
{"protocol": "http", "isPublic": false, "startTime": "2020-12-10T07:45:54.631000+00:00"}
{"protocol": "http", "isPublic": false, "startTime": 1607586354.631}
```

Comment: Custom json_encoders are deprecated as of v 2.0; that's why the link above is broken.