# Return list representation in pydantic root validator

Tags: python, pydantic

I am using pydantic to validate data from a REST API and really like the package so far:

```
from datetime import datetime
from typing import Optional, List, Union
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field, root_validator
from pprint import pprint


my_devices = {
    "devices": [
        {
            "modifyTimestamp": "2022-01-17T13:35:58.597569Z",
            "vehicleId": "VINWVWZZZAUZLW9191234",
        }
    ],
    "modifyTimestamp": "2022-01-17T13:35:58.597569Z",
}


class Device(BaseModel):
    vehicle_id: str = Field(alias="vehicleId")
    modify_timestamp: datetime = Field(alias="modifyTimestamp")


class DeviceList(BaseModel):
    __root__: List[Device]


validated_data = DeviceList(__root__=my_devices["devices"])
print(validated_data)

validated_data_list = [v.dict() for v in validated_data.__root__]
print(validated_data_list)
```

which retuns:

```
__root__=[Device(vehicle_id='VINWVWZZZAUZLW9191234', modify_timestamp=datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 17, 13, 35, 58, 597569, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc))]
[{'vehicle_id': 'VINWVWZZZAUZLW9191234', 'modify_timestamp': datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 17, 13, 35, 58, 597569, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)}]
```

But accessing `__root__` and creating a list from it seems a bit complicated to me.

Is this the only way to implement/obtain the (original) list and dict representation in `validated_data_list` directly?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I got your question right, you're looking for the `.json()` method of BaseModel class.

```
from datetime import datetime
from typing import Optional, List, Union
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field, root_validator

my_devices = {
    "devices": [
        {
            "modifyTimestamp": "2022-01-17T13:35:58.597569Z",
            "vehicleId": "VINWVWZZZAUZLW9191234",
        }
    ],
    "modifyTimestamp": "2022-01-17T13:35:58.597569Z",
}


class Device(BaseModel):
    vehicle_id: str = Field(alias="vehicleId")
    modify_timestamp: datetime = Field(alias="modifyTimestamp")


class DeviceList(BaseModel):
    __root__: List[Device]


validated_data = DeviceList(__root__=my_devices["devices"])
validated_data_list = validated_data.json()
print(validated_data_list)
```

Output:

```
[{"vehicle_id": "VINWVWZZZAUZLW9191234", "modify_timestamp": "2022-01-17T13:35:58.597569+00:00"}]
```

Now, since you didn't declare any serializer for the `datetime` field, Pydantic has converted the `datetime` to `str` using its default, which gives you the "+00:00" part in place of the usual "Z" suffix. You can, however, declare your own serialized to print the date however you like. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66548586/how-to-change-date-format-in-pydantic) has a good explanation on how to do that.

Hope I helped.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot!