# Pydantic preprocessing field value

Tags: python-3.x, pydantic

I have data in which dates are represented as ISO strings. Example:

```
{"name": "John", "last_active": "2021-10-13T17:16:49-04:00"}
```

My Pydantic model:

```
from datetime import datetime

from pydantic import BaseModel

class User(BaseModel):
    name: str
    last_active: datetime
```

I want to achieve automatic date conversion when I do: `User(**data)`. Pydantic actually parses `datetime` object from ISO string automatically, but I also need to convert these dates to UTC timezone, like:

```
datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(iso_str).replace(
    tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc
)
```

What is the clean way of doing this with `pydantic`? More generally, do `pydantic` provide hook for preprocessing the passed data?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change date format in pydantic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66548586/how-to-change-date-format-in-pydantic)

Comment: @Vinzenz yes it does, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is validators. Here is the documentation for [Pydantic Field Validators](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/validators/#field-validators).

It's possible to write a validator that uses `mode='before'` for validating value before passing it to the model constructor.

```py
from datetime import datetime

from pydantic import BaseModel, field_validator

class User(BaseModel):
    name: str
    last_active: datetime

    @field_validator('last_active', mode='before')
    def force_utc(cls, value: datetime) -> datetime:
        return datetime.fromisoformat(iso_str).replace(tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

It's also possible to use `typing.Annotated` for defining validators.

```py
from datetime import datetime
from typing import Annotated

from pydantic import BaseModel, BeforeValidator


def force_utc(cls, value: datetime) -> datetime:
    return datetime.fromisoformat(iso_str).replace(tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)


class User(BaseModel):
    name: str
    last_active: Annotated[datetime, BeforeValidator(force_utc)]
```

Comment: Thanks for for answer, the example of using `Annotated` to preprocess the input value is amazing