# How to force FastApi to return formatted DateTime

Tags: python, fastapi

According to the documentation, this is how the `datetime` type is returned:

> A Python datetime.datetime.  In requests and responses will be
> represented as a str in ISO 8601 format, like:
> 2008-09-15T15:53:00+05:00

I'm having difficulties dealing with that date format on my front end. Is it possible to force `FastAPI` to return a `DateTime` so it only shows date + hours/minutes/seconds?

Comment: As fastapi uses pydantic under the hood, you might want to have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66548586/how-to-change-date-format-in-pydantic

Comment: its allways just `date_string[:-5]`  and yeah you could just return a string instead of a datetime object ...