# How to use date in "dd.mm.YYYY" format in FastAPI

Tags: python, date, format, fastapi, typing

I'm learning FastAPI on my own, trying to make a tutorial project, but I'm running into some difficulties. I need the api to receive a date in the format “dd.mm.YYYY” and the output to be in the same format. I'm using a schema inherited from BaseModel with a "date" field. In the function, I take as input an object corresponding to this scheme, and the output is dict, where the keys can be a date in the desired format. I tried to search, but ran into the problem "I'm sorry. My responses are limited. You must ask the right questions." I couldn’t find an option to use minimal crutches to make the same date validation for input (in BaseModel) and output (in typing).

I want to get something similar:

```
class MyTestSchema(BaseModel):
    date: Date_dd_mm_YYYY
    # another fields


class MyTestClass:
@classmethod
def my_test_func(data: MyTestSchema) -> dict[Date_dd_mm_YYYY, str]
    # function


@app.post("")
def my_test_api(data: Annotated[MyTestSchema, Body()]) -> dict[Date_dd_mm_YYYY, str]:
    return MyTestClass.my_test_func(data)
```

I assumed that maybe I needed to write a separate class for the date and define the “validate” method in it, but firstly I couldn’t make it work correctly for both input and output, and secondly I thought that maybe there were some solutions instead inventing your own bicycle.

Comment: So what's `Date_dd_mm_YYYY` defined as? You might want to use a `before` validator for your input, and then use a custom serializing function for your output model: https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/validators/#before-after-wrap-and-plain-validators - what errors do you get with your current setup? Do you expect these dates to be keys in a dictionary with a string as the value? One possible solution for pydantic v2 is shown in https://stackoverflow.com/a/76675710/137650

Comment: Maybe I’m using it incorrectly somehow, but I couldn’t write a variant that can be used to validate input parameters and typing output parameters.

Comment: Initially, I wanted some kind of “wonderful” class in which you can define an input parameter (in BaseModel) and indicate that it is the same at the output (for output and for the swagger). Now I’m already thinking about how to indicate in the typing (for the swagger result) that I don’t have strings, but dates in the format “dd.mm.YYYY”. And the same for input parameters ( @validator("date", pre=True) works, but in swagger it says that it is waiting for a date and not a string, and it gives an error with the date).

Comment: Please add an example of what the user is sending and what is the response he is getting.

Comment: For example, request: {"date": "01.01.2024"}, response: {"01.01.2024": true}